# How to prefill the input text of the react native gifted chat and send it

Tags: react-native

i want to prefill the text in the input text field of the react native gifted chat. Below is my code.

```
render() {
return (
  <GiftedChat
    messages={this.state.messages}
    onSend={Fire.shared.send}
    user={this.user}
    renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
    checkedGamerTag = {this.props.checkedGamerTag}
  />
);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a `text` prop for this, can found detail on [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-chat#notes-for-redux).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @gopiNath accept the answer if works for you, it helps others too in choosing correct answer.

Comment: Oh Sure. Forgot that. Thanks